# How to append another string to the value of a form before submitting?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form like the following, and I want append the value in "hidden" item to "search" item before submit :

```
<form action="...." method="get" accept-charset="utf-8"  >
<input type="search" name="a1" results="0" value="" placeholder="some texts" class="search-form-input"><!-- search value -->
<input name="a1" type="hidden" value="string to be added"><!--hidden value-->
</form>
```

but the result url will like that ...a1=string+to+be+added

Later I try to use the javascript to get the search value and hidden value and combine them:

```
<form action="...." method="get" accept-charset="utf-8"  >
<input type="search" name="a1" results="0" value="" placeholder="some texts" class="search-form-input"><!-- search value -->
<input name="a2" type="hidden" value="string to be added"><!--hidden value-->
<script language="javascript">
var a;
a =     document.getElementsByName('a1').value + 
document.getElementsByName('a2').value;
alert(a);
</script>    </form>
```

but the pop-up alert says: NaN.

How to use javascript to joint the 2 value before submitting to another cgi-page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Aycan says, or you can use the Forms collection:

```
document.forms[0].a2.value;
```

But if you run it from the form's submit listener, it's even easier:

```
<form onsubmit="this.a1.value += this.a2.value" ...>
```

though it would be better to use a function to do that:

```
<form onsubmit="addValue(this)" ...>

...

function addValue(form) {
  form.a1.value += form.a2.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByName returns an array of elements. You can get first element of this array which is at index 0.

```
var a;
a = document.getElementsByName('a1')[0].value + document.getElementsByName('a2')[0].value;
alert(a);
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.